# Styling buttons generated by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I have generated some buttons using javascript to use in html and css: The code is as follows:

```js
for(letter in currentQuestion.answers){

          // ...add an HTML button
          answers.push(
            `<label>
              <input class="press" type="button" value="${letter}" >
            </label>`
          );
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I am trying to style this code so that 2 buttons come on each row, however, my code causes the buttons to stack on top of each other. My code is more or less generating buttons from scratch in javascript, query. I have tried using display: inline-block; e.t.c and read up on using grids. Could anyone help me find a solution to my problem? Here is what I would like it to look like:
Question:
Button1 Button2
Button3 
What styling should I use please?

Comment: Have you tried setting label {display: inline-block}?

Comment: Why is there a label around the button?

Comment: We need to see more of your code to know how they are being added to the page and if there are any pre-existing styles that are causing problems.

Comment: A little off-top, but rather than store elements in your array, why not just store the answers and then create and populate the elements when they need to be shown?

Answer (score 0):

```
    let answers = []
    let rest = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    for(letter in rest){
          // ...add an HTML button
          answers.push(
            `<div class="inner">
                <label>
                  <input class="press" type="button" value="${letter}" >
                </label>
            <div>`
          );
        }
        console.log(answers)
        $('.appendHere').append(answers)
```

HTML

```
<div class="appendHere"></div>
```

CSS

```
.appendHere .inner{
  float: left;
}
.appendHere .inner:nth-child(2n + 1){
  clear: left;
}
```